# Random number between two points, needs to be both negative, positive or a mix

Tags: java, math, random, numbers, generator

I'm writing code for a kind of minigame in another game (Minecraft) in Java and I stumbled upon a problem.

I have two ints, int point 1 and int point 2. They are x coordinates, from ex: -100000 to 100000. But also -10000 to -5000, and 10000 to 20000. So negative to positive, but also negative to negative and positive to positive.

And that is the problem. I need to find a solution how to get random numbers from ex -100 to -50. But the same code has to be used with -100 to 50, and 10 to 50.

If you guys can help me, that'd be great!

Greetings,

Jesse.

PS: If you need a code snippet or something, just say it.

Comment: Duplicate : https://www.google.ro/search?q=java+generate+random+number+in+range&rlz=1C1OPRB_enRO540RO540&oq=java+generate+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.3748j0j2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I googled alot and could not find negative to negative examples, this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Jesse It makers not difference whether the values are negative or positive. The first Google hit of Silviu's search works for all value ranges.

Comment: @Jesse: Good joke. Random.nextInt(n) generates a number between 0 and n-1. Random.nextInt(50) generates an int in range 0, 49. For -25, 25 range, simply add -25 :) Basicly: Random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min.

Comment: It **is** a duplicate.... just use negative Min and/or Max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int mix = Math.min(point1, point2) + (int)(Math.abs(point1 - point2) * Math.random()));
```

EDIT:

```
int mix = Math.min(point1, point2) + Math.round(Math.abs(point1 - point2) * Math.random()));
```

EDIT2 :

```
int mix = Math.min(p1, p2) + (int)Math.round(-0.5f+(1+Math.abs(p1 - p2))*Math.random());
```

The distirubtion of this expression evaluation seems to be probably better. But this is not an optimised solution in fact.

Comment: Other solutions on SO will work as well.

Comment: This solution will never return 'Math.max(point1, point2)' which is part of the requirements.

Comment: But now it will return point1 and point2 50% fewer times than other values in the range..... so it's not random....

Comment: It is not nessissary to leave old revisions of your answer in, the revision history is there for anyone who wants to see it

Comment: I didn't know that, I will take care of it the next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Silviu Burcea's comment contains a google search which answers your question.  Numbers are numbers.  It doesn't matter what sign they have.  So going to the first result from the google search gave the answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        // just modified the line from the other thread 
        // which was "int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;"
        int i = rand.nextInt(-50 - -100 + 1) + -100;
        System.out.println("Next value = " + i);
    }

}
```

That prints out pseudo random numbers between -100 and -50.  So yeah, your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Your modifications break the code..... The `+1` has to be inside the `nextInt(...)` call. Your answer makes the value `-100` impossible to get.

Comment: @rolfl: fixed it.  But the cusp of my answer was that what the poster was looking for already existed just as Burcea commented.

Comment: That may be, but if you provide example code as a solution, then it should be right (or you should expect to be critiqued)

Comment: I'm fine with that, assuming I'm wrong.  Technically, his question didn't specify inclusive or exclusive end points, so I *could* argue my answer is fine.  But I also see that I inadvertently altered the code I was referencing, so it could be wrong from that standpoint.  Indeterminate = -1?